# Default project structure and run configuration for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, configuration

I downloaded IntelliJIDEA to code JavaFX applications.

For the first time, I opened a project and I had to add the library to File->Project Structure->Libraries and then edit the VM options by going to Run->Edit Configurations. I notice that the two steps I had done was modified for the current project only.

Then from the main menu, I added JavaFX library to Global Libraries and changed the VM options in application templates but still after opening new project, I have to add them manually again.

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: Go to Tools->Save project as Template

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File | New Projects Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EXzx.png) menu to customize the defaults.

It's also possible to save your project as template: Tools | Save Project as Template.

Comment: @user and CrazyCoder, I tried the save project template and it works totally fine. I don't know why the New Project Settings doesn't happen to work on linux.